# Font Awesome not working with HTML5 UP template

Tags: html, css, templates, fonts, font-awesome

I'm trying to create a website using a template from [HTML5 UP](https://html5up.net/) (Arcana). The structure of the template looks like this:

> /assets
>   /assets/css
>   /assets/fonts
>   /assets/js
>   /assets/sass
>   /index.html

When not modifying anything, the template works as intended and all icons from Font Awesome are shown correctly ([like here](https://html5up.net/arcana)).

Now I want to structure my sites like this:

> /assets
>   /assets/css
>   /assets/fonts
>   /assets/js
>   /assets/sass
>   /foo/page.html
>   /bar/page.html
>   /index.html

Now when I open `/foo/page.html` the style and Font Awesome icons are missing because the references to them are messed up.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />`
`<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>`

I tried to fix it like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css" />`
`<script src="../assets/js/main.js"></script>`

Now the style works again, but the Font Awesome icons are still shown as boxes.

I also tried including Font Awesome like this:

`<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

However, the icons still don't work.

Changing 
`<a href="#" class="icon fa-twitter"></a>`
to 
`<a href="#" class="icon fa fa-twitter"></a>`
doesn't work either.

**Update**: For some reason this doesn't work in Firefox, but it works in MS Edge without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

**old**

`<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

**new**

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">`